# Can I override the action MacOS 10.8 performs for the triple-finger-tap gesture?

Tags: macos

MacOS looks-up the word under the cursor in Dictionary.app when you triple-finger-tap. Instead I would like to open a new tab in Chrome and Google that keyword. Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/‎)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mike is right, Better Touch Tool can do the exact same thing you want. I was really lost when I upgraded to 10.7 and all its new gestures : BTT allowed me to restore my old 10.6 gestures.
Download Better Touch Tool for free [here](http://blog.boastr.net).

Then open the Better Touch Tool preferences.

1. Select Gestures
2. Then be sure to select Global in the side bar. That way the new gesture will work in every app
3. List item
4. Click on *Add New Gesture*
5. Select the gesture to override : it should be *Three finger tap* or *Three finger click*
6. Then select the appropriate action : there is a predefined *Search selected text with Google*
7. Done ! You may have to disable the three finger gesture in System preferences.

[image: BTT preferences windows]

[image: Step 5]

[image: Step 6]

Comment: This works, but I have to select the text first. With the existing three finger gesture, it selects the text under the cursor as well. I'll see if I can make it do that with some research.

Comment: K, as a hack, I made it a two stage gesture. Fake-double-click first (selects word—generally), and then open in Google! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de) is an application that lets you assign configure gestures and trigger actions from your Trackpad. I'm not sure if it will allow this specific case but you should definitely be able to get something close.